# Device only boots to fastboot

Tags: fastboot

After turning off the phone . I tried restart the device but it only boots to fastboot. I tried the volume up and power button one but it automatically boots to fastboot. I also tried flashing with MiFlash tool but I accidentally Flashed clean all and Lock after the flash the device booted to Fastboot mode again. Now if I try flashing it says error “not allowed in Locked state. Please help me fix it . Device name: Redmi Note 8 pro

Comment: try *'fastboot continue'*

Comment: thanks for the help . It says "Failed (remote: not support on security) "

Comment: try to unlock bootloader from mtkclient https://www.droidwin.com/unlock-bootloader-on-mediatek-devices-using-mtkclient/

Comment: thanks I will let you know if it worked !! thank you

Comment: sorry it didn't work

Comment: copy-paste exact steps and terminal output of mtkclient into your question (windows mark with right mouse click and hit enter). (post formatting: type four leading spaces for lines of code, or use three `\`\`\`` backticks markdown for code block)